# Finding special characters in XML with Preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, xml, preg-match

I have an xml which returns this format

`<row site_id="999" sale_id="49612" payment_type="MOD_TICKET" pay_payment_info="TICKET=49600" />`

I am able to retrieve the record into an array using
preg_match as follows

```
<!-- $line = trim($line);
if(preg_match("/^<[^$]+\ \/>$/", $line))
{
    preg_match_all("/([^=<\s]+)=\"([^\"]+)\"/", $line, $m);
    $result = array();
    foreach($m as $n)
     -->
```

However, this works but if the XML return something like

```
<row site_id="999" sale_id="49612" payment_type="MOD_TICKET" pay_payment_info="~$TICKET=49600" />
```

The search does not work, how do I add those two characters (~$) into the search

the

Comment: To parse XML you should probably use xml parser, not regex. But the reason why it is not working is probably your first preg_match

preg_match("/^<[^$]+\ \/>$/" - this means match < followed by any number of symbols that are not $. Does not make any sense to me.

Comment: or save yourself from that and just use `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML`

Comment: @yu_sha thank you for the enlightenment

Comment: @user1430825 check my answer it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `simplexml_load_string()` to parse the **XML**

```
<?php
$xml  = '<row site_id="999" sale_id="49612" payment_type="MOD_TICKET" pay_payment_info="TICKET=49600" />';

$obj = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo "<pre>";
foreach($obj->Attributes() as $key => $val){
    print_r($key);
    $val = (array) $val;
    print_r($val[0]);
}
```

Reference :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php